# Running a `ThreadPoolExecutor` only until a number of results have been returned

Tags: python, concurrent.futures

In my code, I have the following lines:

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor() as pool:
            for results in pool.map(load_bucket, buckets):
                 res_list.append(results)
```

I'm trying to break the map, as soon as the list `res_list` reaches a certain length. I've tried the following:

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor() as pool:
            for results in pool.map(load_bucket, buckets):
                if len(res_list)- bucket_size < number_reviews:
                    res_list.append(results)
                else:
                    break
```

This doesn't seem to work.

Comment: the moment `pool.map` is called, the functions runs and returns all elements in a list, this list is then passed to the loop, so by the time the loop starts iterating, the "work" is already done.

Comment: i have to ask if you can precompute the number of iterations required, like are `bucket_size` and `number_reviews` constant ? if so then you can just slice the `buckets` list to be of the correct number.

Comment: @AhmedAEK Unfortunately, I don't think I can... Do you know of an alternative using threads?

Comment: @AhmedAEK alternative to map, using concurrent threads.

Comment: I still like @AhmedAEK 's suggestion. Is there is a reason why you can't? `pool.map(load_bucket, list(buckets)[:bucket_size + number_reviews])`. Once you submitted all of the things in `buckets` the thread pool is going to continue executing them even if you find a way to break out early. Fundamentally, you have to limit the items submitted or waste background processing.

Comment: @AhmedAEK Oh... I think I may have misread your comment. 
Yes, bucket_size and number_reviews are constants!

Comment: @tdelaney I think I misread his comments. Yes, bucket_size and number_reviews are fixed. ;)

Answer (score 0):

the best option here is to use `ThreadPoolExecutor.submit` instead of `map` as `map` will construct the entire output as a list before starting the loop, while `submit` will return `feature`, and later convert the returned futures to the actual output after the loop is done, note that if you don't want to block the main thread waiting for the second loop to finish then you can use run this inside AsyncIO loop as it is easily converted to awaitable function (or just run this code in another thread).

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from concurrent.futures import as_completed

def do_work(input_val):
    print(input_val)
    return input_val

if __name__ == "__main__":
    buckets = list(range(10))
    res_list = []
    actual_results = []
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as pool:
        for entry in buckets:
            if len(res_list)  < 5:
                res_list.append(pool.submit(do_work,entry)) # returns futures ,not actual return
            else:
                break

        # futures must be converted to the actual return
        # output is in finish order, not submission order
        # for submission order remove the 'as_completed'
        for entry in as_completed(res_list):
            actual_results.append(entry.result())

    print(actual_results)
```

and the result is (out of order):

```
0
1
2
3
4
[2, 0, 1, 3, 4]
```

Comment: This isn't any better than just grabbing the first 5 items and using pool.map.

Comment: @tdelaney I can imagine a situation where this is better, because the second loop can be delayed until the data is needed, but you are correct that more knowledge about the program is needed.